failed to get filesystem from image: error removing bin to make way for new symlink: unlinkat //bin/sh: permission denied
I'm trying to build a Docker image for my Spring Boot app using a CloudBees CI pipeline. Since I'm unable to use Docker due to permissions issues, I've decided to use Kaniko to build the image. However, I'm encountering issues during the build process.
Here's my setup:
this is my Dockerfile
# build the app
FROM maven:latest AS build
ENV home=/home/app
WORKDIR ${home}
# Copy everything from the current directory into /home/app
COPY . ${home}/
# builds the project, packages it, and installs the artifact into the local Maven repository
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# create the final image
FROM openjdk:latest
WORKDIR ${home}
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-jar", "app.jar"]

this is jenkinsfile
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - 9999999
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegedContainer: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: jenkins-docker-cfg
        mountPath: /kaniko/.docker
  volumes:
  - name: jenkins-docker-cfg
    projected:
      sources:
      - secret:
          name: docker-credentials 
          items:
            - key: .dockerconfigjson
              path: config.json
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build with Kaniko') {
      steps {
        container(name: 'kaniko', shell: '/busybox/sh') {
          sh '''#!/busybox/sh
            /kaniko/executor --context `pwd` --destination arijknani009/test-kaniko:latest 
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

What I've tried:
I've checked the Kaniko documentation and confirmed that my executor command seems to be correct.
I've verified that the Dockerfile is valid and can be built manually using Docker.
